# Calling functions in OpenMP fortran threads

Tags: function, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have a basic question. In the code below, I am calling the same function, 'add', twice. When I do this using OpenMP, I'm getting incorrect results.

```
program p
integer::i,j,omp_get_thread_num,n
real::suma
i=5
j=10

!$omp parallel num_threads(2) private(n)

n=omp_get_thread_num()

if(n==0) goto 1111

suma=add(i,n)

write(*,*)'sum for 5=',suma,n,i

goto 1000

1111 suma=add(j,n)

write(*,*)'sum for 10=',suma,n,j

1000 continue

!$omp end parallel

end program p
!----------------------------------------

function add(k,n)result(l)

implicit none

integer::k,s,n

real::l1,l

!write(*,*)'thread employing me is:',n

l1=0.0

do s=k,k+5

l1=l1+s

end do

l=l1

return

end function add
```

The result of executing this code is:

```
sum for 10=   45.0000000               0          10

sum for 5=   45.0000000               1           5
```

However, when I uncomment line 22, ie '!write(*,*)'thread employing me is:',n'

the result is:

```
 thread employing me is:           0

 sum for 10=   75.0000000               0          10

 thread employing me is:           1

 sum for 5=   45.0000000               1           5
```

What should I do in order to employ the same function using different threads, correctly(ie without mixing up the variables) Can anyone explain the results obtained?

This is a simplistic version of my actual problem. (where I'm using the same function in threads)

Edit: Ok, I've realized the very silly mistake of not including 'suma' in the private list. But still, can someone tell why, if line 22 is uncommented, it always gives the correct result, even if suma is not made private?

Comment: My guess would be that the `write` statement somehow is some kind of "implicit barrier", s.t. different write statements from different threads are given line-by-line instead of garbled.

Comment: You should add `suma` to the list in the `private` clause. And you should really use OpenMP sections.

Answer (score 4):

There is a data race condition in your program. `suma` is `shared` (by the implicit data sharing rules of OpenMP) and both threads assign to it at the same time. Uncommenting the `write` statement results in slight offset in the execution of the second thread and therefore hides the race condition (it doesn't on my OS X - it just makes the program randomly print two times `45.0` or two times `75.0`).

```
!$omp parallel num_threads(2) private(n, suma)
...
!$omp end parallel
```

Besides that, you should really really really use OpenMP sections instead of the `goto` logic that you have employed:

```
!$omp parallel num_threads(2) private(n, suma)
n=omp_get_thread_num()

!$omp sections
suma=add(i,n)
write(*,*)'sum for 5=',suma,n,i
!$omp section
suma=add(j,n)
write(*,*)'sum for 10=',suma,n,j
!$omp end sections

!$omp end parallel
```